# How do you run Homebrew internal tests?

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I have some test modifications for the `homebrew` project but when I try and run them:

```
$ ruby Homebrew/test/caveats_spec.rb 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from test/caveats_spec.rb:4:in `<main>'
    1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- formula (LoadError)
```

What gives?  I don't see a rakefile either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears the canonical way is via

`brew tests` which runs all internal tests with the right include path setup.

And to run just one file like `tests/caveats_spec.rb`  (gleaned from `brew tests --help`)

`brew tests --only caveats`